# How to get "FirstInstallVersion" of adobe acrobat reader using powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to get the `FirstInstallVersion` (value `19.010.20069`) for Adobe Reader.

```
$value = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Adobe\"Acrobat Reader"\DC\Installer\* |
    Select-Object FirstInstallVersion |
    select-string 'Acrobat Reader' |
    out-string
```

But I get blank, can any one help me please?

[image: powershell]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always worth reading the documentation for commands [Get-ItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) as they contain examples of how it can be used.

[Example 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) show the use of the `-Name` param which you need to use:

```
$value = Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\Installer" -Name FirstInstallVersion | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FirstInstallVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on my machine:

```
$value = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\Installer\' -Name FirstInstallVersion |Select-Object -ExpandProperty firstinstallversion
```